# Time series cross validation with caret

Tags: r-caret

I know using 'timeslice' in `trainControl` allows for time series cross validation, but it seems as if it progresses through the training set one sample at a time.

Is there any way to perform the same cross validation strategy while specifying the number of splits for 'timeslice'?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you would like to achieve? I am not completely clear what would be the desired output. If you could simulate a time-series and desired folds I am certain a solution could be found.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check `createDataPartition()` also in caret R package.

Among the user defined resampling methods for `trainControl()`, the function parameter `method = 'timeslice'` will allow you to use the arguments that should be given to the time series version of `createDataPartition()`, namely `createTimeSlices()`.

You can set the number of consecutive values in each training set sample (`horizon`); if a `fixedWindow` should be used for the rolling-origin time series cross validation procedure; and how many resamples (in this case, time observations) to `skip`. Then, the *number of splits* to be specified it can be set by using both `horizon` and `skip` parameters.